# Nodemailer + Handlebars + NextJS - The correct path

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, next.js, nodemailer, vercel

I'm experiencing problems to find the right path settings in `production` for my nodemailer/handlebars setup.
The transporter is connected to an API request in order to send an automatic email.

In `development` I'm leaving the configuration as is, so basically I have this situation:

```
module.exports.ViewOption = (transport, hbs) => {
  transport.use('compile', hbs({
    viewEngine: {
      extname: '.hbs',
      partialsDir: 'static/js/mail/views/email',
      layoutsDir: 'static/js/mail/views',
      defaultLayout: 'contacts'
    },
    viewPath: 'static/js/mail/views',
    extName: '.hbs'
  }));
}
```

No problems here, everything works fine.

On `Now` instead, I'm receiving this exception:

[image: Screenshot 2019-11-06 at 10.47.57.png]

The request returns an ok response as you can see here:

[image: Screenshot 2019-11-06 at 10.48.10.png]

So I concluded that the problem is related to the wrong path set on transporter config. I can't live it like on `dev` because it redirects on `/var/tasks`. The problem is that I've tried different ways to locate the file path correctly, without success:

- Using `__dirname +'<path>'`
- Placing it in plain such as `/<path>...`
- Setting the one inside `_next` production dir: `/_next/static/....`

This is my current filesystem:

[image: Screenshot 2019-11-06 at 10.48.39.png]

[image: Screenshot 2019-11-06 at 10.49.25.png]

As you can see, I've the config file both inside on `/static/js/mail/config` than `/_next/static/js/mail/config`. None of both worked, the call responses every time with the same error, independently by its path.

This is my current `now.json` if it could be helpful:

```
{
  "public": false,
  "name": "LC",
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [{
    "src": "/resume",
    "dest": "https://lucacattide.dev/static/html/resume.html"
  }, {
    "src": "/robots.txt",
    "dest": "https://lucacattide.dev/static/robots.txt"
  }, {
    "src": "/sitemap.xml",
    "dest": "https://lucacattide.dev/static/sitemap.xml"
  }, {
    "src": "^/service-worker.js$",
    "dest": "/_next/static/service-worker.js",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "public, max-age=43200, immutable",
      "Service-Worker-Allowed": "/"
    }
  }],
  "env": {
    "RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY": "@recaptcha",
    "SMTP_SERVICE_HOST": "@smtp_host",
    "SMTP_SERVICE_PORT": "@smtp_port",
    "SMTP_SERVICE_SECURE": "@smtp_secure",
    "SMTP_USER_NAME": "@smtp_name",
    "SMTP_USER_PASSWORD": "@smtp_password",
    "SMTP_LOG_NAME": "@smtp_log"
  },
  "github": {
    "enabled": true,
    "autoAlias": false
  }
}
```

Anyone experienced this before or could help me in some way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your now.json look like? Is it possible that you're not building your static folder like this: `{
      "src": "/static/*",
      "use": "@now/static"
    }`

Comment: Hi @Edrian, I removed the ```builds``` section due to this [docs warn](https://zeit.co/docs/runtimes#advanced-usage/advanced-static-builds-usage). I updated my question with my current ```now.json``` configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated on [GitHub](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/issues/269#issuecomment-562529760), at last I found the cause of `__dirname` misconfiguration, related to the *Webpack* configuration. As suggested on StackOverflow, by deactivating it on *Webpack*, as follows:

```
{
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  }
}
```

Only the `__dirname` from Node configuration is being used on client-side.

But, unfortunately, this doesn't solve my situation, because *NextJS* uses more than one *Webpack* config - both for server-side than client-side - so in my case, if I try to modify the client-side one, the returned path points to *NextJS* `/pages/api` folder.

Due to the fact that by the serverless environment of my current Hosting - [Zeit.co](https://zeit.co) - is impossible to my to set up a proper `express` custom server as I would, I finally opted for a third-party service - [EmailJS](https://emailjs.com).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is right answer to this question, but I was facing something similar to next js and email templating and found from nextjs docs and also found it to be working: attaching the code sample attached here.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using **resolve** from the **path** package fixes the issue. (At least for me).

```
import { resolve } from "path";

module.exports.ViewOption = (transport, hbs) => {
    const templateDir = resolve(process.cwd(), "static/js/mail/views");
    transport.use('compile', hbs({
        viewEngine: {
            extname: ".hbs", // handlebars extension
            layoutsDir: templateDir, // location of handlebars templates
            defaultLayout: "contact", // name of main template
            partialsDir: templateDir, // location of your subtemplates aka. header, footer etc
        },
        viewPath: templateDir,
        extName: ".hbs",
    }));
}
```